# Why can't I import cv2 from anywhere else than install dir?

Tags: python, opencv, python-import

I'm using anaconda with spyder on Win 10. I installed opencv by pip-install opencv-python.
If I do

```
import cv2
```

in the default directory (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3), it will work.
However, if I do the same command anywhere else I'll have an error :

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-c8ec22b3e787>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

If I want to run a script which needs cv2, I have to go in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 , then import cv2 and finally run my script in whatever directory I want. 
I don't have this problem with other modules, like pygame or pillow.

Comment: Do you have any other python installed in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because the IDE may contain many Interpreter and the `cv2` library is not installed for the python Interpreter which is set for the system, try to install the `cv2` with command prompt using `pip install opencv-python`. then it may work for you from any location.

Comment: That's what I did. I removed every python related program, clean the best I could with ccleaner, rebooted and then only installed anaconda. Then I made

    >pip install opencv-python

and I still have the problem. I tried with

    >pip install opencv-contrib-python but had the same problem

I think it's a windows & python environment related problem, because I don't have this problem on a virtualised Xubuntu.
Unfortunately, I need it to work with Windows...

Comment: Ok now follow up the steps : first install the `python` in your system again and then follow up the link [link to setup pip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYdHr-LxsJ0) after the pip is setup in your system install the library using command prompt `pip install opencv-python` and then you can import it form anywhere in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Abhishek-Saini.
Following [this video where pip directory is added to PATH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYdHr-LxsJ0), I added C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin to path. And, it works ! (for now, then)